# Need explanation on strings "<%= text %>"

Tags: javascript, string

Can anyone explain to me how this works? '<%= someTextIdontKnow %>'.

I've seen codes with strings looks like shown above. Need a thorough explanation on this please. Thanks :)

P.S. I've seen it on a javascript file, I should have tag asp if it was.

Comment: u sure it's javascript and not an asp.net code?

Comment: I used it when i wanted to get values from the back code( asp.Net )

Comment: It must be some template language of some framework which i dont know about. It is definitely neither to js nor to string relevant.

Comment: You should tag this with the appropriate framework. It's not Javascript. If you've used it for ASP.NET, surely you know what it does?

Comment: Where have you seen this? It could be in an erb template (typically used in Ruby on Rails), or as others have suggested, an ASP.NET page. If you're looking for a thorough explanation you need to ask a clear question.

Comment: yes, it's a javascript code. I've seen it on grunt.js. Also, I've seen   and used as a template on other libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

@meetmahpuppy
You can see this under .ejs as a templating language
https://www.ejs.co/

However, this standard of syntax is similar in Ruby, PHP, which is known as interpolation. Interpolation is where you render something based on data provided by your backend (or server).

As a rule of thumb, 
the `<%=` means 'render something onto my markup based on this data variable, whereas `<%` doesn't render

Other variations of syntax for interpolation can be seen under handlebars (Angular, Ember) with the following`{{ text }}`

Comment: +1 in comparing it like handlebars. That explains all of the thoughts on mind :) thanks (can't vote :()

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of inline expression in ASP.NET:

<%...%>

<%=...%>

<%@...%>

<%#...%>

<%$...%>

<%-...%>

<%@...%>

Please read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112 for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%=  %>
```

usually used in asp.net to render / bind a variable from server side
i.e :

```
<%= Eval("vacancy.title") %>
```

or

```
 <%= Bind("vacancy.title") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In an HTML page you can use `<% %>` to access the serverside code of the page (ASP.NET).
It is executed when the page is rendered. `<%= someTextIdontKnow %>` is short for `<% Response.Write(someTextIdontKnow) %>` and it writes the content of the variable (as a String) into the HTML code.

The link to the [Knowledgebase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5.aspx)

Example to write an error-text from a resource file into the HTML:

```
<div class="error">
    <%= Resources.Com.ERR_failureAction_lbl%>
</div>
```